# int * cast of constants

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int *i,*j;
  i = (int *) 60;
  j = (int *) 20;
  printf("%d\n", i - j);
}
```

What will be the output of this code? I have worked a lot with pointers, but never came across such a code.

Comment: You should always return something explicitly from `main`.

Comment: you definitively have a compiler that is much too permissive. Did you switch all warning levels to maximum? For gcc this would be `-Wall` e.g. This is not a correct declaration of `main` and the difference between two pointer is generally not an `int`. It is of type `ptrdiff_t` which often can be a `long`. Use "%ld" for the format and cast the result of the pointer difference, `(long)(i - j)` if your compiler doesn't support "%td".

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behavior since you're subtracting pointers which do not point inside the same array object.

> When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object**, or  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  array 
>   object;  the  result  is  the  difference  of  the subscripts of the
>   two array elements.

It might also be undefined behavior for other reasons, like using pointers to invalid objects.

> I am getting an ouput of 10..but couldn't figure out how?

Setting aside the undefined behavior, if `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your machine, then indeed there are 10 integers between the addresses `20` and `60`. That's what pointer subtraction gives you: **the difference in number of elements**.

---

As `teppic` mentioned, your printf is wrong. The difference between 2 pointers is a `ptrdiff_t`. The format should be something like `%td`.

Comment: Although it's undefined, it will work on most machines because array elements are stored in memory one after the other. The compiler knows how large an int is, and is just assuming that the memory addresses are valid pointers to parts of an array. Your printf() function is wrong, as you're printing a pointer as %d.

Comment: You probably mean `"%td"`, `ptrdiff_t` is signed, obviously.

Comment: @cnicutar: what is ptrdiff_t? what is _t .

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

main()

{

int a[3][2][4] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24};

printf("%d\n", **(*a+1));

}

what will be the output of this??..very tricky it is...

Answer (score 1):

A pointer that is neither a null pointer nor points to a valid object is an invalid pointer. Any use of an invalid pointer, like reading its value, is undefined behavior.